# batch to search in a folder

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, file-conversion

I am trying to write a batch file . which looks in a folder for specific files, takes their path and uses them for calling a java script: for example: i have a folder cbacklog in desktop which include ***.xls** file and i have a **converter.js** java script. i want to look in **cbacklog** if it has excell files , i will take this file path and call **converter.js** converter will convert this file. then batch file will move to next excell file... take its pats and uses it for convert.js

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var xls03Path = WScript.Arguments(0);
xls03Path = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(xls03Path);

var xls95Path = xls03Path.replace("cbacklog", "dbacklog");

xls95Path  =xls95Path.replace(/\.xls[^.]*$/, ".xls");


var objExcel = null;



try
{
    WScript.Echo("Saving '" + xls03Path + "' as '" + xls95Path + "'...");

   objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");

    objExcel.Visible = false;


    var objExcl = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(xls03Path);

    var wdFormatxls = 39;
    objExcl.SaveAs(xls95Path, wdFormatxls);

    objExcl.Close();

    fso.MoveFile(xls03Path,"C:\\Users\\cguneyel\\Desktop\\cbacklog\\processed\\");

}
finally
{
    if (objExcl != null)
    {
        objExcl.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have only java script for now @r3ap3r

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in ("c:\somewhere\cbacklog\*.xls") do cscript converter.js "%%~fa"
```

for each xls file in folder call the script with the full path to file as argument

Comment: to call my javascript i use this:  cscript.exe //nologo //E:jscript C:\Users\user\Desktop\cbacklog\converter.js C:\Users\user\Desktop\cbacklog\test.xls

Comment: @user32, if you are running it from command line, replace `%%` with `%`. The command, as it is written, is for batch file which needs percent signs escaped. What problem do you have with with the way you call your script? The `//nologo` is just to not show "logo", the `//E:` is not needed in this case as it is infered from the script extension and the full path to the .xls file is being passed as argument. Where is the problem?